# jenkins triggered job runs only at certain time of day

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a JobA which once complete triggers JobB, JobC, JobD.

I am trying to have JobB start immediately. Then, JobC and JobD to have the build requests in queue until is 10PM at night.

JobA is triggered at 12PM. So right now, I am using the option of Quiet period of 5hrs. It would be really nice if JobC and JobD could do as mentioned above.

Is this possible in Jenkins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is by writing a small [Groovy Postbuild](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) script.

You would basically call [**scheduleBuild**](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html#scheduleBuild(int,%20hudson.model.Cause)) and supply a quiet period based on how many more seconds till 10PM.

Here is some untested pseudo code:

```
def duration = tenPM - now;
manager.build.project.scheduleBuild( duration.seconds, new Cause.UpstreamCause( build ), new ParametersAction(params));
```